# Creating Dendrogram with ggdendrogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, dendrogram, ggdendro

I'm doing cluster analysis and creating a dendrogram. I used `ggdendrogram` package and want to use its output in `ggplot2`. I wonder how get the same x-labels as the leaf-labels. Thanks

```
D1 <- as.dist(
  matrix(
    data=
    c(   0,  9, 3, 6, 11
      ,  9,  0, 7, 5, 10
      ,  3,  7, 0, 9,  2
      ,  6,  5, 9, 0,  8
      , 11, 10, 2, 8,  0)
    , nrow= 5
    , ncol = 5
    , byrow=TRUE
    ))

HCD1 <- hclust(d = D1, method="single", members=NULL)
library(ggdendro)
ggdendrogram(HCD1, theme_dendro=FALSE)
```

[image]

```
HCD1Data <- dendro_data(as.dendrogram(HCD1))

library(ggplot2)
p1 <-
    ggplot(data = HCD1Data$segments) +
    geom_segment(aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend))
print(p1)
```

[image]

Comment: why do you show two examples - what is the key difference, and what else do you want to add? (from the question it sounds like the first figure provides what you are looking for, but pardon me if I misunderstood)

Comment: @David -- I believe the OP wants a figure like the second one, but with the x-axis tick labels reading, from left to right, "1", "3", "5", "2", "4" (instead of "1", "2", "3", "4", "5").

Comment: Thanks @David and Josh for showing your interest in my problem. Josh is right that I want the x-axis tick labels reading, from left to right, "1", "3", "5", "2", "4" (instead of "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `scale_x_discrete()` and set your own labels. The same labels as in dendrogram are located in object `HCD1Data` parts `labels` and column `label`.

```
HCD1Data$labels
  x y label
1 1 0     1
2 2 0     3
3 3 0     5
4 4 0     2
5 5 0     4

p1+scale_x_discrete(labels=HCD1Data$labels$label)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 In the new dev version of `ggdendro` I have included this as the default behaviour in `ggdendrogram()`

Comment: @Andrie Nice to hear that :)